# Linguistic synonym of language

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I guess it is pretty clear to see that these two are synonyms but I can suggest it officially.

[language](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language)
[linguistics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linguistics)

Unless someone think there is a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think they are closer than Economy and Commerce. So I have no problem with them being tag-synonyms.